# Local isometry and Hausdorff dimension

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

I am currently reading Falconer's book on Hausdorff dimension. My question is whether Hausdorff dimension is invariant under local isometry between smooth Riemannian manifolds? I think it should be yes, but I am not sure how to choose the covering( needed for calculation of dimension) using the local charts explicitly to get the invariance. Any help would be very much beneficial for my understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is invariant, and in fact this is true in much greater generality than manifolds.

If $X$ is a metric space, and $X$ is not separable, it is easy to verify that the Hausdorff dimension is infinite, and non-separability is of course preserved under homeomorphisms, so without loss of generality assume $X$ is separable (which we typically have in your context anyway).

Define the local Hausdorff dimension*
$\newcommand{\dimloc}{\operatorname{dim}_{\text{loc}}}$ at a point $x\in X$ as

$$\dimloc(X,x)=\inf_{U\ni x}\dim(U),$$

where the infimum is taken over open neighborhoods  $U$ of $x$.

Then it is easy to see from the Lindelöf property that $\dimloc(X,x)\leq d$ for all $x\in X$ if and only if $\dim(X)\leq d$, so that $\dim(X)=\sup_{x\in  X}\dimloc(X,x)$.  Since $\dimloc(X,x)$ is clearly invariant under local isometries, it follows $\dim(X)$ is as well.

##### Remark 1

We could replace “local isometry” with “locally bi-Lipschitz homeomorphism” and the invariance is still assured by the same argument.  In particular, in the context of subsets of a (Riemannian) manifold, Hausdorff dimension is invariant under diffeomorphisms.

##### Remark 2

In general one needs a metric to define Hausdorff dimension, but from the preceding discussion we can see that a coherent definition for smooth, non-Riemannian manifolds can be given using the local dimension defined here, in local coordinates. Such a definition will automatically coincide with the usual Hausdorff dimension whenever said manifold is given any compatible Riemannian structure.

###### *Remark 3

"Local dimension" is a term I just made up for this answer, and is probably not the best name for this quantity, as it misleadingly might suggest that if $\dimloc(X,x)=d$, then there is a neighborhood of $x$ with dimension $d$, when in fact there need not be.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant to say smooth Riemannian manifold. Basically what I meant is that suppose $M$ and $N$ are two smooth Riemannian manifold and $f:B_r^M\to B_r^N$ is a local isometry for some $r>0$. Then whether the dim_H( M)=dim_H(N)

Comment: I just need one clarification.  You mentioned that *Then it is easy to see from the Lindelöf property that $\dimloc(X,x)\leq d$ for all $x\in X$ if and only if $\dim(X)\leq d$, so that $\dim(X)=\sup_{x\in  X}\dimloc(X,x)$*. One side is fine i.e if $dim(X)\leq d$ then $dim_loc(X,x)\leq d$. For the other side if $dim_loc(X,x) \leq d$ then we will choose a open cover of $X\subset \cup U_i$ and using Lindelof property we have $X\subset\sum_{i\in I} U_i$ where $i\in I$ is countable index set. From this line you derive that $dim(X)\leq d$ using countable stability of Hausdorff dimension?

Comment: Let me know whether I had used Lindelof property correctly in the previous argument or it has to be proved by different way. Also just to be sure since local isometry is locally length preserving so if $f:B_r^M\to B_r N$ be local isometry for some $r>0$, then $dim_H(B_rM)=dim_H(B_r(N)$ right? Same kind of argument like Bi-Lipschitz mapa preserve Hausdorff dimension.

Comment: @User11111 re:Lindelof comment, yeah that’s basically right.  In light of third remark, technically the argument is that if local dimension is at most $d$, then cover with open sets where dimension is at most $d+\epsilon$, and use Lindelof to conclude $\dim(X)\leq d+\epsilon$.  Do this for arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ to conclude $\dim(X)\leq d$.

Comment: As for last comment, we always have $\dim_H(B_r(M))=\dim_H(B_r(N))$, these are both just the dimension of the manifold.  What you actually want to say is $\dim_H(U\cap S)=\dim_H(f(U\cap S))$, for any subset $S\subseteq M$.  But yes, this follows from the fact that your Riemannian manifold local isometry is a local isometry in the sense of metric spaces.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I just want to know another thing for my clear understanding about the whole thing. If $G$ and $G_1$ are Lie groups also along with smooth manifolds and for any $g\in G_1$ there exists a $r>0$ s.t map from $B_r^G$ to $B_r^{G_1}$ is an isometry where $B_r(G)$ is $r-$ nbd of identity in $G$ and $B_r(G_1)$ is $r-$ nbd around $g_1$. Then can we say the H-dimensions are same like above? I am bit confused as the map is only from the nbd of identity but since it's a Lie group can we say the local isometry for other nbds also?

Comment: using left translation of the Lie group?

Comment: @User11111 I don't understand the question, if the map is only defined in a neighborhood of the identity then which two sets are you even comparing Hausdorff dimensions of in the first place?

Comment: So, I am asking if both $G$ and $G_1$ are Lie groups and for any $g_1\in G_1$ there is some $r$ s.t the map from $B_r^G$ ( which is $r$ nbd of identity in $G$) to $B_r^{G_{1}}(g_1)$ which is $r$ nbd of $g_1$ in $G_1$ is isometry, then can we claim that Hausdorff dimension of $G$ and $G_1$ are same? I am confused as information around identity is only given.

Comment: @User11111  $G$ and $G_1$ are manifolds, if there is any homeomorphism of any kind between any two neighborhoods of $G$ and $G_1$ then they both have the same topological dimension (by invariance of domain), then since they are Riemannian manifolds their Hausdorff dimension (which is equal to topological dimension) is also the same.

Comment: Yes they are manifolds and for any $g_1\in G_1$ there is a local isometry from nbd of identity in $G$ to neighbourhood of $g_1\in G_1$. I am confused as information only around identity in the domain is given. I am asking if we can say that for other $g\in G$ also we can able to say there is some local isometry using any Lie group structure or we cannot say?

Comment: Also, Hausdorff dimension and topological dimension are same any reference for that. I can ask a new question for that if you wish. As I have seen this statement many times but did't see the proof yet.

Comment: The Lie Group structure has nothing to do with any of this, and no you cannot conclude there is a local isometry anywhere else, unless your metric is translation invariant, in which case of course you get a local isometry everywhere.  But none of that matters because a manifold has the same dimension at every point, and a Riemannian manifold has the same Hausdorff dimension as Topological dimension - Mattila should prove this, according to Encylopedia of Math: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension

Comment: @M W I searched Mattila but couldn't able to find it. Infact the answer in stack are also not clear as they missed all the steps. I have posted this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4813462/967244 yesterday and explained my possible approach. If you have any idea regarding this so that I could write my logic more clearly, please let me know. It would be very helpful. I have seen that statement that Hausdroff dimension is same as dimension of the manifold but didn't find any proper proof anywhere.